# What is the violin's range including all the positions?

Tags: violin, instrument-range

What is the violin's range including the positions(1st position, 3rd position, 5th position, 7th position, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The high range of string instruments is subjective, because theoretically they can extend upwards infinitely. The low note is G3 (with subharmonics, however, this isn't an absolute barrier either).

The high range largely depends on context; I wouldn't write a C8 for a high school orchestra, for example.